# How to automatically find the 'freshest' PPA for a given package?

Tags: ppa, versions

Exact use case:

- I've potentially found a bug in a program (specifically i3-gaps).
- As I don't have the latest version installed the maintainer asked that I install the latest version to check if bug is still there.
- I've originally installed the tool from a PPA. Checking this PPA, there is no version  more recent there. Only version is quite outdated.
- So I'm looking for  other PPAs. I found this page:
  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas?name_filter=i3-gaps
- If I select one PPA, I can get info on the exact version number(s) found there and its/their compile time.
- There are tens of available PPAs. Checking each one manually is tedious...

So my Question: Is there a means/How to automatically find the PPA with the freshest version of a package ? "freshness" could be in terms of version number or compile time (as these 2 metrics seem to be available) ; for the moment I don't care.

Thanks

Comment: I think the best way to obtain latest version is to use GitHub and compile i3 yourself. It's not that difficult. Try it.

Comment: This one is quite fresh, and it is maintained by the regolith team. https://launchpad.net/~regolith-linux/+archive/ubuntu/stable

Answer (score 4):

The answer my be divided in three parts:

1. Search for specific Ubuntu codename is not implemented, but already reported to LaunchPad as [bug 1820387](https://pad.lv/1820387), search for package version is not implemented, you have to report such bug by yourself.
2. Search on local machine maybe done by Y PPA Manager as follows

   - Install it first by

     ```
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
     ```
   - then run search using its GUI or by commandline `y-ppa-search` then specify package name `i3-gaps` to get something like shown below, sort by *Version* column:

     > Search result for 18.04 LTS
     > [image: Y PPA Manager search for i3-gaps]

     and then optionally add PPA with highest version by click on *Add Selected PPA* button, then install newest package by `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.
3. Search on local machine also maybe done by user-created python script named [`pyppasearch`](https://github.com/anenasa/pyppasearch) as follows

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install python3-requests python3-bs4 python3-launchpadlib

   cd ~/Downloads
   wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anenasa/pyppasearch/main/pyppasearch.py
   chmod +x pyppasearch.py
   ```

   Then we can run search using below command:

   ```
   ./pyppasearch.py -c bionic -a amd64 i3-gaps
   ```

   to get results like shown below:

   > ```
   > i3-gaps 4.17.1-1ubuntu1~ppa5 ppa:regolith-linux/experimental Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.18.2-1~regolith2 ppa:rynojvr/ppa Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.17.1-1ubuntu1~ppa4 ppa:kgilmer/regolith-unstable Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.17.1-1ubuntu1~ppa5 ppa:regolith-linux/regolith-1.4.1 Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.17.1-1ubuntu1~ppa5 ppa:regolith-linux/r1.3 Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.19.1-1ubuntu1 ppa:regolith-linux/release Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.19.1-1ubuntu1 ppa:regolith-linux/stable Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.19.1-1ubuntu1 ppa:regolith-linux/unstable Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.17.1-1ubuntu1~ppa5 ppa:a-weller/regolithtest Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.18.2-1~regolith2 ppa:kgilmer/speed-ricer Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.17.1-1ubuntu1~ppa4 ppa:kgilmer/regolith-stable Bionic (amd64)
   > i3-gaps 4.17.1-0york0~18.04 ppa:jonathonf/i3 Bionic (amd64)
   > Search is finished.
   > ```

   They are absolutely equal to those from Y PPA Manager, the differences are in the order of appearance.